# ManyToOne Entity uses insert and update

Tags: hibernate

I have a Survey class which contains Set of SurveyProperties.

Following are the definitions in Survey.java and SurveyProperty.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="survey")
    public Set<SurveyProperty> getSurveyProperties() {
        return this.surveyProperties;
    }


@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id", nullable=false)
    public Survey getSurvey() {
        return this.survey;
    }
```

Now I am populating Survey from a json. Survey contains Set of SurveyProperties which do not contain survey. Now If I save survey object to db, It first inserts into survey, then inserts into survey_property and then updates each survey_property with survey_id.

How should I configure so that it inserts into survey_property with survey_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you save the survey object  set the survey object to  survey_property object.

```
for(SurveyProperty S_P : survey.getsurveypropertylist){
    S_P.setSurvey(survey);
}
```

after that you can use save or update.

Comment: yes done that already. but I was thinking thay may be I am missing some annotation

Comment: No annotation for 3rd level of fetching that data object. relationship objects only used for 2nd level.